# Clear PHP Calculator Screen After Results are Displayed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm making a simple calculator written in HTML, CSS, JS, and PHP. It looks like this:

[image: See Calculator Image Here]

I use JS to get the user input and PHP to do the calculations and output the results.

I want to clear the result when the user clicks on any button.

I've tried `ob` functions in PHP but this prevents any results from showing up in the first place.

I've tried resetting the `innerHTML` of the div with JS with no luck.

Comment: You'll need to present the code so we can understand what you're working with.

Comment: We likely just need the HTML and JavaScript as that is what draws the page.

Comment: Project link is here: https://github.com/kunno/PHP-Calc.git

Comment: Your links to GitHub returns 404. Please paste your code here so people could help you.

Comment: Sorry ladies and gents, I'm a newb here but I figured it out. What do I do with my question if I no longer need help?

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of creating a variable to indicate a new calculation and using it to clear the screen when a number is pressed.

1. Do a calculation
2. Display the answer
3. newCalculation = true;
4. Press a number (for the next calculation)

   ```
   if(newCalculation == true){
       Clear the screen and display the number 
       newCalculation = false;
   }
   ```
5. Press = and display the answer then do it all again.

Comment: I've tried this approach but the problem is that once the calculation is sent to PHP to perform the flag gets reset to its default false value when it returns the answer